# Express.js | http server is not starting code execution immediately after accepting request

Tags: node.js, express, nodes

Expressjs server is executing initial ~2 API calls in queue even if multiple API calls are already done. it is not starting code execution immediately after accepting request and waiting for previous request to finish.

- Getting same behaviour in fastify also.
- Almost same behaviour in plain http server.

Can anyone explain why it's output is like below?

**#Issue Explanation Video**

https://www.loom.com/share/876f1bf5a36c44e59582081c3be09eb5

**#Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let s = {counter: 1};
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let start = new Date();
    let counterValue = s.counter++;
    console.log('start ' + counterValue);
    await tenSecondsTimeoutWait();

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const results = new Date() - start;
    console.log(`end : ${counterValue} in time: ${results}`);
    res.send({'hello': `world ${counterValue} in time: ${results}ms`});
});


app.get('/get', (req, res) => {
    console.log('express get');
    res.send({'hello': `world from get`});
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

async function tenSecondsTimeoutWait() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(1);
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

I started running by below commands and getting same output.

```
node index.js
SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=1024 && node --max-old-space-size=6000 --v8-pool-size=10 index.js
```

**#Output**

```
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
start 1
end : 1 in time: 10008
start 2
end : 2 in time: 10010
start 3
start 4
start 5
start 6
start 7
start 8
end : 3 in time: 10003
start 9
end : 4 in time: 10002
start 10
end : 5 in time: 10003
end : 6 in time: 10005
end : 7 in time: 10006
end : 8 in time: 10006
end : 9 in time: 10010
end : 10 in time: 10001
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in chrome browser,

- This behavior is only with chrome. Somehow chrome is not sending requests to the server.
- When we try with cmd opening multiple tabs and hit request using curl request will start executing immediately, check output of cmd below.

```
start 1
start 2
start 3
start 4
start 5
start 6
start 7
end : 1 in time: 10006
start 8
start 9
end : 2 in time: 10011
start 10
end : 3 in time: 10009
start 11
end : 4 in time: 10007
start 12
end : 5 in time: 10016
end : 6 in time: 10008
end : 7 in time: 10005
end : 8 in time: 10005
end : 9 in time: 10002
end : 10 in time: 10003
end : 11 in time: 10001
end : 12 in time: 10004
```